# iOS Swift - canEditRowAtIndexPath table view cell check userid

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to implement tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath function to allow a user to delete a row from a table view. Before allowing them to delete a row we need to see if the row belongs to them, i.e. the content of the row came when they added an item in the DB.

What would be the best way to do this.

Thanks.
George

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your canEditRowAtIndexPath method.

```
var nameObject:PFObject = timelineGroupData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    if nameObject.objectForKey("userer").objectId == (PFUser.currentUser().objectId){

    return true
}

return false
```